# Large data upload using Scala JDBC

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, insert

I am trying to implement a function that uploads around 40 million records to a MySQL database that is hosted on AWS. However, my write statement gets stuck at 94% for an infinitely long time.

This is the command I'm using to upload `df_intermediate.write.mode("append").jdbc(jdbcUrl, "user", connectionProperties)` with `rewriteBatchedStatements` and `useServerPrepStmts` enabled in the connection properties.

This statement works for small number of points(50000) but is unable to handle this large amount. I've also increased the maximum number of connections on the MySQL side.

EDIT: I'm running this on GCP n1-standard-16 machines.

Why could be the reasons that write is stuck at 94%?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Scala really, you are just saying you want to add many many rows into a DB. The quick answer would be to not have all these in the one transaction, and to commit these lets say 100 at a time. Try this on a non-production sql database first to see if that works.